# Using "imagine" and "assuming" for hypothetical situations

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1-  ***Imagine*** that I had some money yesterday, it would have been so fun to go there. (I didn't have money so we didn't go there
>   yesterday.)
>
> 2- ***Assuming*** that I was the guy whom they were looking for yesterday, would they have beaten me? (I wasn't the guy they were
>   looking for.)

I don't know if my examples are good enough to convey my purpose.

Can I use these them, "imagine" and "assuming", in hypotetchical situations in the past with using past simple?

Comment: Imagine and assume do not mean the same thing, are you asking if they can be used interchangeably or how to just them? 7

Comment: Can they be used in such cases? -hypotetchical situations in the past with using past simple-